# Where can I learn about graffiti for my next project?

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

My next project is to design (as a vector graphic) a logo inspired by the so-called [layer](http://www.flickr.com/photos/layer1gfx/5123180954/lightbox/) style of graffiti. As such, I need to learn as much as I can about this particular graffiti style.

It would also be useful to have an online reference for graffiti-inspired graphics in any upcoming projects... Are there any out there?

Answer (score 1):

There's a fairly [comprehensive article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graffiti) in Wikipedia.  The article is a good start, but spend time going through the first party references in the citations.  What may also be helpful is the accompanying article on [Grafitti terminology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graffiti_terminology).